# Angular bootstrap validation done unobtrusively

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently validating forms using the well prescribed method:

```
  <form name="userForm">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': userForm.email.$invalid }" >
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required />
    </div>
  </form>
```

While this is not the end of the world I wondered if there was a less obtrusive way of doing this.  I have already stated the field is required and angular will paint the element with css class based upon it's state.  Could I achieve the same ends with CSS rather than using `ng-class="{ 'has-error': userForm.email.$invalid }"`.  Many thanks

Comment: Invalid element will have `ng-invalid` class + other validation classes.

Comment: Yes, it will also add others like ng-invalid-max depending what has invalidated it.  I just wanted to pick up on this in CSS rather than using ng-class everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style the angular classes in your CSS.

```
.ng-invalid {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.ng-valid {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

If you want to apply it just to inputs rather than creating a border round the form you can use the following too:

```
input.ng-invalid {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```